# How to resolve DESCRIPTION MUST only use the WSDL "import" statement to import another WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

i am writing a `SOA/WSDL` Web Service Client.

When I use that:

```
 Service service = Service.create(this.url, qname);
 Score score = service.getPort(Score.class);
```

I always get this error:

```
24.05.2012 12:59:54 com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser parseWSDL
WARNUNG: Import of http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?xsd=2 is violation of BP 1.1 R2001. Proceeding with a warning.
R2001 A DESCRIPTION MUST only use the WSDL "import" statement to import another WSDL description.
```

so whats the error the url and the qname are rightly converted into its object Type?

Answer (score 2):

The error is most probably NOT in your code, but in the WSDL of the service you are accessing. The error comes from your client-side WSDL parser's validator. My guess is that inside the WSDL's type definition segment there is an inline XML Schema which uses the `<xsd:import>` directive and this is illegal in the context of a wsdl definition.

Answer (score 2):

> DESCRIPTION MUST only use the WSDL "import" statement to import another WSDL description

So, if you are importing another WSDL into one WSDL, then `<wsdl:import>` is valid tag. But, if you are using this tag to import XML Schema Definition, then you will get mentioned warnings at runtime. For example is invalid :

```
<wsdl:import namespace="com.my.schema/v2" location="services.xsd"/>
```

Instead, use `<wsdl:types>` and `<xsd:import>` to import your XML schema definition.

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="com.my.schema/v2" schemaLocation="services.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

It worked for me, so thought of sharing!!